# "Select Reverse Engineering File"- Error while creating Hibernate to POJO mapping files

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, pojo

I am trying to create a Hibernate Mapping between POJOs and the database. I have already created a database and connected that with the project. The JMS resources are also created with `messageQueue`. Hibernate reverse engineering has also been created. However, the modal indicates that there is a problem selecting the reverse engineering. How do I do that?

image:1

[image]

Image:2

[image]

Comment: go through this link - http://wiki.netbeans.org/ReverseEngineering